# How to use Selenium scrape url protect from distil networks by python

Tags: python, selenium

I don't know how to use Selenium get data url protect from distilnetworks by python.

**Error:**

> Validating JavaScript Engine

```
The website www.urlwebsite.com requires that all visitors be running JavaScript. This page is validating your browser\'s JavaScript engine and functionality.

Your web browser will automatically reload shortly and you will receive a pop-up asking you to confirm your form submission again. Confirming the form submission again will allow you to continue to www.urlwebsite.com without further incident
```